# Live chat software for sales driven website

Tags: web-development, chat, shopping-cart

I have a question about which live chat software would better suit my company's needs. We have been using LivePerson but they have changed their user agreements and are now charging for reports on how many daily chats we receive. My company very much needs this feature so we are looking for other options.

I'll start off by listing features we need:

- Reports on how many chats we receive daily
- Reports on what time of the day we receive the most chats
- Reports on what pages the customer visited
- We have 10 CS Reps that need to be chat operators
- We need to be able to see what page the customer is looking at (URL)
- Customized chat windows (Embedded, invite windows, scrolling windows)
- Allowed to set offer windows on certain products if the customer visits them

I'd love to hear what live chat everyone is using on their website and why. I'm open to any suggestions. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: As you used the [tag:web-development] tag, are you looking for self-hosted software that you’d have to integrate yourself with your site, or for a hosted solution?

Comment: I have a similar question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/49458/14834

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you are looking for is available with our product http://www.ChatNox.com
We could talk further if you can come on our website for a chat and discuss. You can also write to me `nicole at chatnox dot com`.

To answer your questions, FYI -

- Reports on how many chats we receive daily - Yes
- Reports on what time of the day we receive the most chats - Yes
- Reports on what pages the customer visited - Yes
- We have 10 CS Reps that need to be chat operators - Highly Scalable solution.
- We need to be able to see what page the customer is looking at (URL) - Yes
- Customized chat windows (Embedded, invite windows, scrolling windows) - Highly customizable, Rule based triggers also available.
- Allowed to set offer windows on certain products if the customer visits them. - Customizable request.

I'm also a adding screen shots of reports and operator console for our product ChatNox Live Chat.

[image: Chatnox.com Operator Console]

[image: Chatnox.com Report-Daily Chat]

[image: Chatnox.com Chat Distribution Report]

[image: Chatnox.com Chat Distribution by type by day]

Disclaimer: I work for ChatNox.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using  [Visitlead.com](https://visitlead.com/features) - and it's quite nice.
It's not so common yet, since it came out recently, but i think it has some really cool features. What i especially like about it is that you are not limited to livechat, instead you have several options to interact with your visitors...

I'll quickly go through your requirements. But many of the features I'll talk about are also described on their homepage - probably a bit better! ;) --> [Visitlead](https://visitlead.com/features)

> *Reports on how many chats we receive daily*

No problem there. That's showed on the dashboard.

> *Reports on what time of the day we receive the most chats*

I'm not sure if this feature is available, but i guess even if it is not you could just ask your operators when they have many chats...? If this does not work you could also use a 11th operator as a kind of a 'emergency operator' - if this one gets visitors, you know that all others are highly occupied. :)

> *Reports on what pages the customer visited*

You have a detailed history about that, for every single visitor and how long he was on every site. You even see if he is 'active' on your site or has another tab open!

> *We have 10 CS Reps that need to be chat operators*

That won't be an issue. We also work with a bunch of and never had any problems.

> *We need to be able to see what page the customer is looking at (URL)*

Now we get to the interesting points. Actually, you do **not only** see the URL, you can also watch the visitor's view. Co-Browsing is a really cool thing when you tried it once!

> *Customized chat windows (Embedded, invite windows, scrolling windows)*

Yes again! There are already some Templates you can work with, but you can edit them as you wish or also can create completely new ones.

> *Allowed to set offer windows on certain products if the customer visits them*

You can do that as well with widgets. You can create as many of them as you wish, completely different or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please improve it by adding information about the features which Visitlead has that would satisfy the requirements in the question? Check [this FAQ for what is required for an answer to be high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/6834)